# Next.js not-found infinite reload loop

Tags: next.js

I'm using next 13.4.4 with app router. I've added not-found.tsx component to app directory, basically just copied code from next documentation:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
 
export default function NotFound() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Not Found</h2>
      <p>Could not find requested resource</p>
      <p>
        View <Link href="/">all posts</Link>
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The problem is, when I navigate to not existing route, 404 page renders correctly, but inifintely reloads.

tl;dr: I've wrote not-found.tsx component. Expected it to just display not found page, but it reloads infinitely.

Comment: Is this in development mode? If so, that's expected behaviour for the 404 page. It shouldn't behave like that in production.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Is this in development mode? If so, that's expected behaviour for the 404 page. It shouldn't behave like that in production."

Thanks juliomalves. Yeah, it was in development mode.

p.s. Weird expected behavior imho, idk why they made it like that.

Comment: The reason why it's been designed this way is because in development ENV you might be trying to access a page you haven't created *yet*.
For this reason, the server refreshes to check if the page you try to reach has been created and avoid you being stuck on the 404 page.

More details here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40000#discussioncomment-3498014

Comment: Thanks i was about to ask this question.